# How to point a custom domain to a Heroku subdomain?

Tags: heroku, subdomain, cname

Is it possible to allow users to use their own custom domains to point to a specific Heroku subdomain? I'm using wildcard subdomains that allow my app to use abc.myapp.com URL's. Could a user add myuser.com and point to that? How can this be done?

Trying to add CNAME to point there returns Heroku | No such app messages and when I add the custom domain to the Heroku Dashboard it just points to the top level domain.

DETAILED STEPS:

CNAME mydomain.com ---> myapp.herokuapp.com -- works fine

CNAME anotherdomain.com ---> sub.mydomain.com -- not working

If I add anotherdomain.com to the Heroku dashboard then:

CNAME anotherdomain.com ---> sub.mydomain.com or mydomain.com -- works fine but opens the root domain mydomain.com in either cases

So I guess the only way to serve the proper subdomain is to handle it inside my app, so that anotherdomain.com in the db corresponds to sub.mydomain.com and serve the proper page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app's code, you need to configure that new domain to point to your app.
This is what you would manually be doing with the `heroku domains:add` command.

Using [heroku's Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#domain-create), you can perform this programmatically.

Comment: When I do add the domain to Heroku it does not point to sub.myapp.herokuapp.com or sub.domain.com but to domain.com directly. It just ignores the subdomain.

Comment: You can't add `sub.myapp.herokuapp.com` subdomains.

Comment: If adding `sub.domain.com` doesn't work, it means there's something you're not doing something properly (though you're not showing us anything you're doing, so it's hard to help you).

Comment: I've updated the question to include the steps taken so far and the result. Hope this helps anyone else avoid the trouble I had to get into. You were right, the only way is to handle it internally in my app and add it to the platform via an API Call.